# In external memory, comparing performance of different C++ self-made tree data structures for answering database queries

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures

I have two tree data structures that I made in C++. I am using [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29). I need help in understanding the way to compare the performance of these two data structures (for database range query / point queries) in external memory. How can I do this?

I searched a lot on the Internet, and I didn't find any clear idea on how this is done. I know I can measure disk [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output), memory consumption, [CPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) usage, etc. using Ubuntu's [dstat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmon#Alternatives), and [iostat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iostat) commands. I need some accurate and professional way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  There are probably several reasons why your question has been largely overlooked.  You didn't tag it with the obvious C++ tag which would have attract many more sets of eyes.  Your question is very open-ended, so it is not clear that it is a good fit for SO.  It is also very far from clear from your question how your two data structures designed for in-memory use will be written to and read from external memory (presumably, that means 'disk' or equivalent persistent storage).  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ For DBMS, the conversion between on-disk and in-memory storage tends to be a dominating factor in the performance. Additionally, how much in-memory caching will be done, and whether you need to worry about concurrent updates in multiple processes, will also affect things. This is before you start dealing with updates, transactions, recovery, etc. So, you will need to detail a lot of requirements. We can guess that you only want to deal with a single process that is single-threaded.  It may be that you can read the structure into memory, update it there, and dump it out.

Comment: I made 2 new datastructures in c++.I want to compare their performances like IOs done, memory addressed and time required to respond to queries.Just want to measure the above written metrics. I recently created and saved these tree indexes & tree structure using xml,on the disk.I can test the IOs,memory used, time taken to respond to the queries in external memory.Question is how to measure these metrics?I thought to run the program in one ubuntu terminal and to run dstat or may be iotop comammnd and to capture the cpu usage,disk ios, etc from there but is there any better way to measure this?

Comment: By In-memory i meant,tree structure that was creating indexes on the columns passed from the dataset & was printing the response of the quering passed but wasn't saving these indexes on the disk.Now i have written another function through which it is saving the tree structure in xml format and bit vector indexes created by this tree onto the disk.Basically i've saved on the disk whatever i wanted to compare its performnace, I just want to know the way to measure the IOs etc while executing my code.